# Share one BindingSource between two forms

Tags: c#, winforms

How to share one binding source between two forms?

Comment: I cant share my Code (((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the reference to the other form (using DataTable as example):

```
public class Form2 {
  DataTable _Data;

  public void SetDataSource(DataTable dt) {
    _Data = dt;
    // set binding of control...
  }
}
```

Then from Form1:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Form2 f = new Form2();
  f.SetDataSource(myDataTable);
  f.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: I think the question is not any data source but specifically how to share one BindingSource object. You approach works ok for sharing data but not for other BindingSource characteristics, for example, the ability to navigate forward and backward, etc.

Comment: @Y.Ecarri That's an odd downvote considering how little information was provided by the OP.  My first sentence was specific: `using DataTable as example`.  It was just a demonstration.  Feel free to post your own answer.

Comment: I'm sorry for the downvote, I didn't mean to hurt anybody but I really think your answer can mislead. It's not the same a "BindingSource" than a "data source". I'm sure one downvote won't affect your reputation too much. I'm sure you are very professional and highly skilled. If you put yourself in my point of view you will have to agree that a DataTable is not a BindingSource. Yes, I could post my own answer but I still don't have one that satisfy myself.

Answer (score 0):

Add a "BindingSource" parameter to the constructor of the form with which you'd like to share the binding source. You can then use that source to set up the bindings of the appropriate controls in the constructor body.

Comment: but when i pass the link on bindingsource through the constuctor, my controls are empty

Comment: When you use a parameter constructor, there are two options: calling the parameter-less constructor first or calling InitializeComponent. In either case, InitializeComponent will replace the bindingsource with a new BindingSource instance and either the bindingsource is empty or all the binding are lost so the fields will be empty.